# Transform CSV into Parquet using Apache Flume?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, etl, flume

I have a question, is it possible to execute ETL for data using flume.
To be more specific I have flume configured on spoolDir which contains CSV files and I want to convert those files into Parquet files before storing them into Hadoop. Is it possible ?

If it's not possible would you recommend transforming them before storing in Hadoop or transform them using spark on Hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably suggest using [nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/) to move the files around.  Here's a specific tutorial on how to do that with [Parquet](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Convert-data-from-JSON-CSV-Avro-to-Parquet-with-NiFi/ta-p/247100).  I feel nifi was the replacement for Apache Flume.

Flume partial answers:(Not Parquet)
If you are flexible on format you can use an avro sink.  You can use a hive sink and it will create a table in ORC format.(You can see if it also allows parquet in the definition but I have heard that ORC is the only supported format.)

You could likely use some simple script to use hive to move the data from the Orc table to a Parquet table.  (Converting the files into the parquet files you asked for.)

Comment: Please upvote if you found the answer helpful.  If you feel it is the correct answer and your comfortable doing so please mark it as "the answer"